# is it possible to access a Document Directory from another app?

Tags: ios

the question is simple,
is it possible to access a Document Directory from another app? with out jailbreak!

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot. Due to app sandbox, you can only limit its own sandbox directory, which acts as the home for the app and its data.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW1

But you can share data via keychain or you can save data on the server.

Comment: He's absolutely right...there is no shared file structure in iOS, period. Great for security, bad for developers. I do see Apple loosening up on this restriction one day, as it's one of the key reasons--and I hate to say this--that Android is passing up iOS in capability.

Comment: Forgot to add: one marginally useful workaround that some developers have adopted is using DropBox integration. So for instance, if you wanted to pass an image between two image-viewing/editing apps, you could load it into dropBox in one app and retrieve it from another. It's a bit clunky and ridiculous, but it does work.